# Optimization of a javascript class flame effect

Tags: javascript, optimization

This class is used to draw an old school flame on a canvas element. I'm wondering if there is any way to speed up the `fire` method. The class is based on old C code.

```
LayerFire = {
    init : function(options, elem) {
        this.options = $.extend({
                width  : '320',
                height : '240'
            },
            this.options, options);
        this.elem  = elem;
        this.$elem = $(elem);

        // Create our buffer
        this.bufferp = [];
        this.buffer = [];
        var i = this.options.width * this.options.height * 4;
        while (i--) {
            this.bufferp[i] = 0;
            this.buffer[i] = 0;
        }

        // Create the palette
        this.palette = [];
        this.makePalette();

        // Initilize our main loop
        var t = this;
        this.updater = setInterval(function() {t.fire.apply(t);}, 125);
    },
    makePalette : function ()
    {
        // make a nice looking color palette for a flame
        for (i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
            this.palette[i] = Object.create(VideoColor);
        }

        for (i = 0; i < 32; i++)
        {
            /* black to blue, 32 values*/
            this.palette[i].b = i << 1;
            this.palette[i].a = 255;

            /* blue to red, 32 values*/
            this.palette[i + 32].r = i << 3;
            this.palette[i + 32].b =  64 - (i << 1);
            this.palette[i + 32].a = 255;

            /*red to yellow, 32 values*/
            this.palette[i + 64].r = 255;
            this.palette[i + 64].g = i << 3;
            this.palette[i + 64].a = 255;

            /* yellow to white, 162 */
            this.palette[i + 96].r = 255;
            this.palette[i + 96].g = 255;
            this.palette[i + 96].b = i << 2;
            this.palette[i + 96].a = 255;
            this.palette[i + 128].r = 255;
            this.palette[i + 128].g = 255;
            this.palette[i + 128].b = 64 + (i << 2);
            this.palette[i + 128].a = 255;
            this.palette[i + 160].r = 255;
            this.palette[i + 160].g = 255;
            this.palette[i + 160].b = 128 + (i << 2);
            this.palette[i + 160].a = 255;
            this.palette[i + 192].r = 255;
            this.palette[i + 192].g = 255;
            this.palette[i + 192].b = 192 + i;
            this.palette[i + 192].a = 255;
            this.palette[i + 224].r = 255;
            this.palette[i + 224].g = 255;
            this.palette[i + 224].b = 224 + i;
            this.palette[i + 224].a =  255;
        } 
    },
    fire : function() {
        // create a ransom flame at the bottom of the screen
        y = this.options.width * (this.options.height- 1);
        for (x = 0; x < this.options.width; x+=3)
        {
            var random = 1 + (16 * ((Math.random() * 32767) / 32767) + 1.0);
            if (random > 11) {
                /*hot*/
                this.bufferp[y + x] = 200; 
                this.bufferp[y + x + 1] = 255;
                this.bufferp[y + x + 2] = 200;
            } else {
                this.bufferp[y + x] = 50; 
                this.bufferp[y + x + 1] = 20;
                this.bufferp[y + x + 2] = 50;
            }
        }

        // move the flame up                        
        var top = this.options.height;
        if (top > 110)
            top = 110;  
        for (index = 0; index < top ; ++index)
        {
            for (x = 0; x < this.options.width; x++)
            {
                if (x == 0) /* at the left border*/
                {
                    temp = this.bufferp[y];
                    temp += this.bufferp[y + 1];
                    temp += this.bufferp[y - this.options.width];
                    temp /= 3;
                }
                else if (x == this.options.width - 1) /* at the right border*/
                {
                    temp = this.bufferp[y + x];
                    temp += this.bufferp[y - this.options.width + x];
                    temp += this.bufferp[y + x - 1];
                    temp /= 3;
                }
                else
                {
                    temp = this.bufferp[y + x];
                    temp += this.bufferp[y + x + 1];
                    temp += this.bufferp[y + x - 1];
                    temp += this.bufferp[y - this.options.width + x];
                    temp /= 4;
                }
                if (temp > 1)
                    temp -= 1; /* decay */

                this.bufferp[y - this.options.width + x] = Math.round(temp);
            }
            y -= this.options.width;
        }

        // copy the palette buffer to display buffer
        for (x = 0; x < this.options.width; x++)
        {
            for (y = 0; y < this.options.height; y++)
            {
                var index = (y * this.options.width + x) * 4;
                var c = this.bufferp[(y * this.options.width) + x];
                //console.log(c);
                this.buffer[index+0] = this.palette[c].r;
                this.buffer[index+1] = this.palette[c].g;
                this.buffer[index+2] = this.palette[c].b;
                this.buffer[index+3] = this.palette[c].a;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Working demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jzaun/qscru/).

Comment: Do you have a runnable example (perhaps in a jsFiddle)?  It's hard to run performance tests on a piece of code that you can't run because you're missing pieces that are need to make it run or don't know what sequence to call it to make it run.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really an expert on speed optimization, but here are some thoughts:

- You should keep references/copies to often used objects/values instead of accessing them repeatedly through properties, e.g:

```
var bufferp = this.bufferp;
var width = this.options.width;
var height = this.options.height;
```

- There are some variables (such as `x` and `y` which you haven't declared as local with `var`).
- What is the point of `(Math.random() * 32767) / 32767`? As far as I can tell it does nothing.

Answer (score -2):

(Math.random() * 32767) / 32767 - induced giggles. :)

(Not very helpful I know but hey, ‘we can’t all be Astronauts’)

Comment: This looks a comment to [RoToRa's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/10206/93149) - just comment there, and or post your own [answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).